# Answer box "Editing Help" button misplaced in Firefox

Tags: bug, firefox

I saw this in Firefox 41.0.2 and Firefox Developer Edition 43.0a2.
[image: firefox-screen-shot]

Chrome shows it correctly. (46.0.2490.80 m)
[image: Chrome-screen-shot]

Comment: Seems to be caused by the `left: 639px` on the containing `<li>` element (tested in FF 41.0.2)

Comment: It used to show up with the question mark centered on the line. I thought it was on purpose!

Comment: Seems like the toolbar box and the text box don't have the same width in Chrome. #everypixelcounts

Comment: Same in firefox ESR 38.0.1.

Comment: Dupe on Big Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250561, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259344